# Excel table search funcion that looks for partial string match

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

Hi have an Excel document made of 2 pages.
In the first page there is a table with 5 columns (Date, Mail, Telephone, Name, Number and Total spent) and there are about 3000 rows already and i add daily about 20 rows manually.
In the second page i am trying to make the research bar so that when i type any if the 5 criteria it returns all the rows from the first page where it finds a match.
I managed to do it but as of now i only get results if i type exactly the string, that includes spaces and capital letters so if i search for "Mark" but i type "Mark " or "mark" it doesent find anything.
I'd like to have something that finds even partial matches; to be more clear i'll have an example.
If in the first page under the name column i have "Mark B.", "mark", "Mark C." or "Markus" when i type mark in the search bar i want all 4 rows to appear.
I know it's a bit confusing but engligh is not my first language, sorry in advance.
Thanks

As of now i have the research page set up with a drop down list in cell C3 with all the 5 column names so that if i want to search by telephone i select it so it know to look for matches in the telephone column and so on..
My current formula is:

`=IFS(C3="DATA";FILTER(DATABASE!A2:F29; DATABASE!A2:A29=RICERCA!D3);C3="MAIL"; FILTER(DATABASE!A2:F29; DATABASE!B2:B29=RICERCA!D3);C3="TELEFONO"; FILTER(DATABASE!A2:F29; DATABASE!C2:C29=RICERCA!D3);C3="NOME"; FILTER(DATABASE!A2:F29; DATABASE!D2:D29=RICERCA!D3))`

Problem with this is it finds only exact matches but i want it to find everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SEARCH` with wild cards:

```
=FILTER(Database,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*" & D1 & "*",Database[Name])))
```

As you haven't provided sample data I am using a simpliefied example:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, you're right i should have posted an example sheed. Thanks for the help !